# mysqldump writes dumped data to output

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump, cron

I'm trying to bring incremental backups to one old setup. The script I create worked perfectly when run directly. However when I run it from crontab or when redirecting shell output all data is written to stdout.

```
mysqldump --compact -T /some/backups/$db/ $db
```

It looks like `-T` doesn't work correctly in this case. Can someone share any experience of creating backups in a `-T` way?

Thank you.

Comment: When running from `cron` you're going to have to specify the full path to the output directory

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ, yep, I'm doing exactly that. The script doesn't change at all and under cron it just writes data to stdout.

Comment: @kworr - `_backups/$db/` is not a "full path", it is "relative" to the current directory.

Comment: @RickJames, 0k, I fixed that in the question.

Comment: How about building a test case that anyone could run.  Perhaps the "redirecting" case would be simpler than providing crontab commands.